# Error Handling in C? How to deal with scanf and illegal characters?

Tags: c, unix

I'm writing a program in C, and for error handling it tells you to look for an illegal character when you're scanf-ing. In other words, look for a character that isn't an integer.
It is supposed to display an appropriate error message and terminate the program.

I'm a little confused as to how I go about looking for that illegal character, or noticing that it isn't an integer. Any help?

Comment: What have you got so far? Also, is this `homework`?

Comment: Posting your code would really help us to help you.

Comment: I was just wondering in general, how would the scanner know if it wasn't an integer?

Comment: Show us your scanner line and we'll be able tell you.  Force the user to enter an integer.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf()` returns the number of successful arguments. If you do:

```
int ivar, return_val;
return_val = scanf("%i", &ivar);
```

`return_val` should be 1, cause of 1 parameter (`ivar`). Check the user input:

```
if (return_val == 1) {
    // right input
} else {
    // wrong input
}
```