# C. Printing error messages due to user entering letter instead of number

Tags: c, custom-errors

The user has to enter a number greater than 0 in order to print some stuff.

my code for when the user enters a number less than 0 uses a while loop. It then asks the user to type in a number again.

```
while(x<=0){
  print("Must enter a number greater than 0");
  printf("Enter a number: ");
  scanf("%i",&x);}
```

How can I create an error message formatted similarly to the one above, but for a user who enters a "x" or a word. Thanks

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9724261/error-handling-in-c-how-to-deal-with-scanf-and-illegal-characters) too

Comment: For starters, you need to check the return value from `scanf()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the reading is done using [scanf](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) with a numeric format, it means that if you enter something that can't be read as an integer (`123`) or part of an integer (`123x` is ok, the parsing stops soon after the 3), the scanf fails (i.e. it can't parse the input as number). Scanf returns the number of successfully parsed items. So you expect 1 in your case. You can check the return value (if it's 0, scanf wasn't able to get any number from the input) but as said before you still accept thigs like `123x` (and the "residual" x will be parsed in the next scanf from stdin, if you do it).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(void){
    int x;
    int ok=0;

    do{
        char buff[32], *endp;
        long long num;

        ok = !ok;//start true(OK)
        printf("Enter a number: ");
        fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), stdin);
        x=(int)(num=strtoll(buff, &endp, 0));//0: number literal of C. 10 : decimal number.
        if(*endp != '\n'){
            if(*endp == '\0'){
                printf("Too large!\n");
                fflush(stdin);
            } else {
                printf("Character that can't be interpreted as a number has been entered.\n");
                printf("%s", buff);
                printf("%*s^\n", (int)(endp - buff), "");
            }
            ok = !ok;
        } else if(num > INT_MAX){
            printf("Too large!\n");
            ok = !ok;
        } else if(x<=0){
            printf("Must enter a number greater than 0.\n\n");
            ok = !ok;
        }
    }while(!ok);

    printf("your input number is %d.\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```